# Google Maps White Space

Tags: android, google-maps

I know there are similar questions, but i could not find any solution.
I programmed an Android application which uses Google Maps.
Unfortunately i only get an white space on my device!

It works on my friends device and other application (which use Google Maps) work perfectly well at my device.

Internet and W-LAN allowed of course.
What could be wrong here? I have tried nearly anything without any success.

Comment: Android somehow caches the google maps API key. If you had run the app via Eclipse/USB cable using your debug key, and now are trying by exporting the app, creating a .apk and using the production key - it will sometimes not work.  Try deleting the app from your device and then installing it.

Comment: Sorry I don´t quite get it. I am pretty new to this stuff. I just ran the application and it installed itself on my device. I just tried to export it but that can´t be the right way since it shows a lot of errors, although it works at my friends device.

Comment: UPDATE: Well since my friend send me his version, I didn´t change a thing. So it´s his API key and everything else refers to him. Could this be a problem? But wouldn´t that mean the app can only run at his device? Sorry for the beginner questions...

Comment: Update your question explaining the steps you did to obtain the google map key, your manifest file, and how you built and installed the app on your device and your friends. I don't understand the part of your friend sending you "his" version - isn't this your app and didn't you give it him?

Comment: We are working at it together, sharing data via dropbox. So it should say it´s "our" app. So I wasn´t sure if i had to change something now. Paths, the API key... i don´t know... we both followed some tutorials and we both don´t really know if we can even share this app so easily. We send it to our devices using "run as" => "android app" and we share it by packing it into a zip file, uploading it on dropbox and importing it into ours workspace.

Comment: Post the logcat - it will likely say something about the map and may give you a clue as to what is going on.  There are really too many possibilities.